# WPF "static" binding in a List

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, binding

I have a problem with a binding in a List.

I have a List of objects. This List is bound to a ListBox. Of every object in my List I can open a ContextMenu:

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
  <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ContextMenu>
          <MenuItem Header="First"  IsEnabled="{Binding FirstEnabled}"/>
          <MenuItem Header="Second"  IsEnabled="{Binding SecondEnable}"/> 
        </ContextMenu>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

In the code like this my objects in the list having the two booleans to bind. Now I want to bind this two booleans not to the objects. I want to bind it "static" to my DataContext. This is not working like this and I have no idea how to realize it.

I googled a lot but found nothing helpful ...

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, `ContextMenu` applies to `ListBoxItem` it will have its `DataContext` value and `ListBoxItem` will be its `PlacementTarget`. So if you want to bind to property of `ListBox.DataContext` you need to pass current `ListBox.DataContext` as, for example, `Tag` to `ListBoxItem` and then you need to refer to it from `ContextMenu` via its `PlacementTarget`. It's all because `ContextMenu` uses `Popup` which [creates its own visual tree](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms749018(v=vs.100).aspx#PopupandtheVisualTree) so simple `RelativeSource`/`ElementName` binding won't work

```
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}, Path=DataContext}"/>
    <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="First"  IsEnabled="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}, Path=PlacementTarget.Tag.FirstEnabled}"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Second" IsEnabled="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}, Path=PlacementTarget.Tag.SecondEnable}"/>                    
            </ContextMenu>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: great answer. Worked! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference every datacontext with the ElementName Syntax:

```
<ListBox x:Name="myListBox">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
       <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
           <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
               <Setter.Value>
                   <ContextMenu>
                       <MenuItem Header="First"  IsEnabled="{Binding Path=DataContext.FirstEnabled, ElementName=myListBox}"/>
                       <MenuItem Header="Second"  IsEnabled="{Binding Path=DataContext.SecondEnable, ElementName=myListBox}"/> 
                  </ContextMenu>
               </Setter.Value>
           </Setter>
       </Style>
   </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

With this syntax you use the DataContext of your ListBox and not from the ListItem.