# How do I bind a command to a Listbox Item?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, listbox

I have a Listbox. I have the ItemSource of the Listbox bound to a list.

Within the ItemTemplate, I want to be able to add a MouseBinding to each item.

Here's what I have so far:

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Border Background="Blue" CornerRadius="8" >
            <Border.InputBindings>
                <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftClick" Command="{Binding Test}" CommandParameter="{Binding PropertyOfClickItem}" />
            </Border.InputBindings>
            <TextBlock Foreground="White" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="5">
                <TextBlock.Text>
                    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}, {1} &#x0a;Seat: {2}">
                        <Binding Path="LastName" />
                        <Binding Path="FirstName" />
                        <Binding Path="Seat" />
                     </MultiBinding>
                 </TextBlock.Text>
             </TextBlock>
         </Border>

      </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

I'm confused, because it seems that I can only bind to things within my ItemSource, but my "Test" command is not within that. How can I bind to a Command that's in the ViewModel for the View, instead of the ItemSource that's bound to the Listbox?

Not only that, but I want to be able to pass a property of the selected item to the command. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`RelativeSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.relativesource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of the binding to get an ancestor that has the DataContext you want. For example:

```
Command="{Binding DataContext.Test, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a Relative Source like clcto said.

Look here for a complete answer:
[WPF "static" binding in a List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32537261/wpf-static-binding-in-a-list)